# could not allocate space for object in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I am getting database exception.

> Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.ITEMS'.'PK_ITEMS' in database 'MyDatabse' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

My current database size is 10GB.

[image]

My server details are

[image]

Is there any limitation that R2 supports only 10GB. How could we increase this.

Comment: The limitation is SQL Express. Consider upgrading to SQL Standard Edition (not free).

Comment: Cleaning up some huge tables can handle this too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The limitation is because you're using SQL Express](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2010/04/21/database-size-limit-increased-to-10gb-in-sql-server-2008-r2-express.aspx), which is the free version of SQL Server. In case your database exceeds this, you should probably upgrade to SQL Server Standard Edition.

Comment: Thank you for response. could we do it without loosing our existing database.

Comment: @Patan - You have to do a fresh install of SQL Server, but you can easily create a backup of your database and restore it to the new installation.

Comment: okay. How can we identify if we are using free version of sql server.

Comment: I have added the screen shot of my server details. Could you help if this is a standard version or free version.

Comment: Run the query SELECT @@VERSION  That will display the full version string. You may need to expand the column

Comment: @HardeepRandhawa - Yeah. Don't use GoDaddy.